# Using std::cout on STM32 microcontroller

Tags: c++, arm, microcontroller, cout, stm32

I managed to use `printf()` on my STM32 (CortexM7) compiling under C++, by defining functions like `_write` and `_read` and so on.

But I wanted to use std::cout instead of `printf`. However including `<iostream>` yields like 300 errors.

Do you know what has to be done to use `cout` with custom char printing functions?

Compiler used G++ 6.2.

---

I have found partial solution. You can make class (even name it cout) and overload operator << for different types and inside execute printf() with proper format string. Maybe not most efficient but for UART is ok.

So I don't need answer anymore, but if someone knows, then for curiosity you can post it.

Comment: I'm not familiar with C++ for STM32 (used C with NXP in the past) but `std::cout` is basically an [`std::ostream`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ostream/ostream/) which writes to [`stdout`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/stdout/) so as a hint I would derive a class from [`std::streambuf`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/streambuf/streambuf/) and define its `virtual` methods to write and read as it's expected then I would use it with `std::ostream`.

Comment: Check your compiler documentation.  There may be hooks that you need to satisfy, since the STM32 can be put on any kind of platform.  Also, the implementations of `std::cout` and `printf` are implementation dependent.

Comment: Please edit your post with the compiler that you are using.  There are many compilers that can be used with a STM32 microcontroller, such as IAR, Greenhills and GNU.

Comment: the compiler really isnt the issue, what if any operating system are you running on the stm32 (generally none but sometimes an rtos) and then what C library that is modified/created for that target (can make baremetal ones but you still have to port/target them or find a ready to use one).   you are significantly better off using neither of these library calls/features.  they are some of the most massive in backend requirements for such a resource limited environment.

Comment: make your own library routines and recover a significant percentage of your flash for other more useful things.

Comment: to your question the problem you are facing is a backend there are going to be many many layers of library functions required and they boil down into system calls.  Plus before you hit that problem you have to point the generic compiler at the specific library and header files you want to use